# Failing to connect to MongoDB (Mac)

Tags: mongodb

I've followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WJ8m5QHvwc) and installed and uninstalled MongoDB a handful of times. I occasionally can connect, but the majority of the time I can't and run into this error:

```
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=40879 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=XXX
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-10-18T01:19:21.747-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-18T01:19:21.747-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-18T01:19:22.124-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-18T01:19:22.124-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-10-18T01:19:22.126-0700 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname XXX: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I've looked a few threads and have seen these solutions thrown around:

1. `killall mongod` *(doesn't appear to work)*
2. Updating the host name in the `/etc/hosts` file, although I can't find this file anywhere

Any help with either of these two steps or guidance on other steps would be appreciated. Additionally, I keep seeing the 'soft rlimits too low' error -- what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Could you please specify:
   1) The exact mongod command line you tried. 
   2) Any other error you are seeing in the logs. 
   3) Is the dbPath directory you are supplying to the command line writable by the user mongod is running as. 
   4) The MongoDB version you’re running.

Comment: Did it really say `XXX` for the hostname in your config?

Comment: @NikhilJagtiani
 1) I tried the `mongod` command as both my user and super user
 2) These are all the errors
 3) Yes
 4) 3.2.10

The weirdest thing is that it's happening sporadically. I just tried it again and it worked back-to-back (after Ctrl + C'ing).

@ThomasR.Koll No, sorry. I just replaced it for simplicity.